# Is the closure of $(0,+\infty) \cap (0, a)$ compact in $(0,+\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, compactness

Consider the half-line $(0,+\infty)$ as a topological subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose I consider an open interval $(0,a)$ for some $a > 0$. The set $(0,+\infty) \cap (0,a)$ is open in $(0,+\infty)$. If I am not mistaken, its closure should be $(0,+\infty)\cap [0,a]$. The closed interval $[0,a]$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}$, so my question is: is the closure $(0,+\infty) \cap (0,a)$ compact in $(0,+\infty)$ as well?

Comment: Does the open cover $\{(1/n, a + 1/n)\}_{n \ge 1}$ have a finite subcover?

Comment: @RhysSteele, it does not. Is there any compact near the origin then?

Comment: If by "near the origin" you mean "containing a set of the form $(0, \varepsilon]$" then the answer is no by similar reasoning.

Comment: @geetha290krm That does not cover the point $a$ of the suspected compact set $(0,a]$

Comment: Compactness is, informally speaking, a property not affected by its *sup*space, i.e. a subset $B$ of $A$ (where $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$) is compact wrt the subspace topology  (induced by the usual one on $\mathbb{R}$) on $A\iff$ $B$ is compact wrt the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$. (It is not hard to prove this statement.) So you can use the "bounded and closed" criterion to see if $(0,a]$ is compact.

Comment: Why did you write $(0,+\infty)\cap (0,a)$ instead of $(0,a)$?

Comment: I just wanted to make it explicit that I was seeing this as a subset of the topological subspace $(0,+\infty)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a comment, I don't really know why you are writing the set as $(0,\infty)\cap (0,a)$, since this set is simply $(0,a)$.

Second, no, the set is *not* compact in $(0,\infty)$. There are several ways to prove this.

1. From definition of compactness (i. e. every open cover has a finite subcover), you can create a sequence of open intervals that become smaller and smaller as they approach $0$. This sequence will not have a finite subcover.
2. From sequences (in metric spaces, every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence), you can take a sequence that converges to $0$ and there will be no convergent subsequence of it.